# Multiple Route parameters angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I have two parameterize routes

```
 { path: 'mails', component: MailsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
 { path: 'mails/:label', component: MailsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'mails/folder/:folder', component: MailsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
```

In the component i want to get routes parameter based on condition .

```
ngOnInit(): void{ 
    if (this.googleAuth.stateFlag) {
      // labels
      this.route.paramMap.subscribe(route => {
        this.label$ = route.get('label');
        this.googleAuth.selectedEmailLabel(this.label$);
      });
    }
    else {
      // folder
      this.route.paramMap.subscribe(route => {
        this.folder$ = route.get('folder');
        console.log('folder handle:', this.folder$);
        this.googleAuth.selectedEmailFolder(this.folder$);
      });
    }
}
```

Although there is condition, every time it executes else block.

Comment: Just look at the value of `this.googleAuth.stateFlag` in the debugger or by logging it to console.

Comment: this.googleAuth.stateFlag is true @ Aluan Haddad

Comment: `if` statements work.

Comment: no if statements not work  but if i routes http://localhost:4200/mails then if statement works.But why?? @Aluan Haddad

Comment: You must be mistaken. It is not possible that `if` statements are broken. You have incorrectly observed your programs behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely because `ngOnInit` is only called once in the component's life, and the component can be used multiple times on route changes. Try subscribing to the paramMap once, and handling logic within:

```
ngOnInit(): void{ 
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(route => {
    if (this.googleAuth.stateFlag) {
      this.label$ = route.get('label');
      ...
    } else {
      this.folder$ = route.get('folder');
      ...
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: what is the best way to component re-initialization?

Comment: @limon7 You will want to create a custom RouteReuseStrategy and always return false for `shouldReuseRoute`, but this is a fairly complex method to implement. If you want to clear data on paramChanges, you can also do this in your `subscribe( route => { ... })`, which would be the easiest/fastest.